# Turn led when both sw1 and sw2 are pressed in TIVA

Tags: c, arm

I'm trying to turn red LED when sw1 and sw2 are pressed. This current code can turn blue LED with sw1 and green with sw2 (TM4C123)

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "inc/hw_memmap.h"
#include "inc/hw_types.h"
#include "driverlib/sysctl.h"
#include "driverlib/gpio.h"
#include "inc/hw_gpio.h"

uint8_t sw1=2;
uint8_t sw2=2;

int main(void)
{
    SysCtlClockSet(SYSCTL_SYSDIV_5|SYSCTL_USE_PLL|SYSCTL_XTAL_16MHZ|SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN);

    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOF);

    HWREG(GPIO_PORTF_BASE + GPIO_O_LOCK) = GPIO_LOCK_KEY;
    HWREG(GPIO_PORTF_BASE + GPIO_O_CR) |= 0x01;
    HWREG(GPIO_PORTF_BASE + GPIO_O_LOCK) = 0;

    GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3);

    GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_4);
    GPIOPadConfigSet(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_STRENGTH_2MA, GPIO_PIN_TYPE_STD_WPU);


    while(1)
        {

        sw1 = GPIOPinRead(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_4);
        sw2 = GPIOPinRead(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0);
            if (sw1 == 0b00010000 && sw2 == 0b00000001)
                {
                    GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1, 0xFF);
                }
            else if (sw2 == 0b00000001)
                {
                    GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2, 0xFF);
                }
            else if (sw1 == 0b00010000)
                {
                    GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_3, 0xFF);
                }
            else
            {
                GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3, 0x00);
            }
            GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3, 0x00);

        }
}
```

With this code, TIVA turns on red LED and change to blue or green when the switches are pressed.
I think the problem is with the condition I used in the first `if`, what should I use to turn red LED when sw1 and sw2 are pressed?

Comment: What about placing `GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2 | GPIO_PIN_3, 0x00);` inside the first condition to turn off unwanted LEDs, similarly in other conditions, and remove the line that finanly turns them all off.

Comment: You cannot implement button management like this. When you press a button there is a phase during which the signal "bounces" between high and low, so your LEDs will toggle unexpectedly. Have a look to "debounce filter" on the web.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean that is true, but it shouldn't stop a student exercise from showing the LEDs accordig to instantaneous button state. That is the first step before implementing debouncing anyway.

Comment: @WeatherVane fair enough. Another point: I don't understand the latest `GPIOPinWrite`. the LED 1 will toggle.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean on the assumption that `0x00` turns off the selected outputs and `0xFF` turns them on, my suggestion was that when `GPIO_PIN_1` is turned on, you should turn off LEDs `GPIO_PIN_2 | GPIO_PIN_3` not wanted. In the code, selected LEDs are turned on briefly and all three are immediately disabled.